# How to sum two rows by a simple condition in a data frame

Tags: r, database, dataframe, sum

I'd like to sum rows 2 by 2, in order to study the lag of certain variable.

Suppose that I have the following the data base:

```
> SE eggs
  4  2.0
  6  4.0
  7 10.0
  8  0.5
  5  1.0
  1  3.0
  2  6.0
  3  9.0
```

So, I expected to obtain the following, where `eggs`are the sum of the indexes "SE"'s:

```
> df
    SE2    eggs
  "4+5"    3
  "6+7"    14
  "8+1"    3.5
  "2+3"    15
```

Where

```
df = data.frame(SE=c(4,6,7,8,5,1,2,3),eggs = c(2,4,10,0.5,1,3,6,9))
```

Obs.: Don't mater the order of the data frame, but I need to start from certain number (in this case, number 4), and then take the next number, in this case, number 5, and keep this logic. After SE 6+7, SE 8+1, SE 2+3...

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: Check out the `zoo` package.

Comment: @novica that's a bit vague. Can you elaborate? How are `eggs` calculated?

Comment: Hm, the order seems to be different in `df` at the end, I guess OP is just after something like `aggregate(. ~ ceiling(seq_along(SE)/2), FUN = sum, data = df)[, -1]` where we group by every 2 rows and sum

Comment: @zx8754 yeah, the SE is an index.

Comment: @arg0naut91 that's what I thought, but it would seem `SE` is the index to use.

Comment: Why 4+5 and not 4+6?

Comment: I tried to edit to be more understandable. @zx8754, because don't mater the order of the data frame, but I need to start from certain number (in this case, number 4), and then take the next number, in this case, number 5, and keep this logic. After SE 6+1, SE 2+3...

Comment: @Ga13 is there any logic in grouping the indices (`SE`) together or it's arbitrary?

Comment: @arg0naut91, there is a logic. I tried to explain in the comment above.

Comment: Can you please add some more example rows? Just to be sure about your logic.

Comment: For sure @tmfmnk. Just did it

Comment: @RomanLuštrik apologies. I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get the logic. You want ascending numbers starting from 4. When these numbers reach 8 (or whatever the maximum value of SE is), they wrap around back to one and continue to ascend until all the numbers are used up.

You then group these numbers into sequential pairs.

For each pair of numbers, you find the rows of your data frame with the matching values of SE. These rows contain the two values of eggs you wish to sum.

```r
df = data.frame(SE=c(4,6,7,8,5,1,2,3),eggs = c(2,4,10,0.5,1,3,6,9))

first <- 4
i <- match(df$SE, c(first:nrow(df), seq(first - 1)))
groups <- ((seq_along(i) + 1) %/% 2)[i]

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, groups), function(x) {
  data.frame(SE = paste(x$SE, collapse = "+"), eggs = sum(x$eggs))}))
#>    SE eggs
#> 1 4+5  3.0
#> 2 6+7 14.0
#> 3 8+1  3.5
#> 4 2+3 15.0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Match `c(4:8, 1:3)` to `SE` using the match indexes to index into `eggs`, reshape into a 2x4 matrix and sum each column.

```
k <- 4   # starting index
nr <- nrow(df)  # no of rows in df

with(df, colSums(matrix(eggs[match(c(k:nr, seq_len(k-1)), SE)], 2)))
## [1] 3.0 14.0  3.5 15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, just a slight variation on my comment where we re-arrange the rows according to the specified logic and then `aggregate` every two rows:

```
aggregate(
  eggs ~ ceiling(seq_along(SE)/2),
  FUN = sum,
  data = df[with(df, order(factor(SE, levels = c(seq(SE[1], max(SE)), SE[!SE %in% seq(SE[1], max(SE))])))),]
  )[, -1]

[1]  3.0 14.0  3.5 15.0
```

Or, if you'd like to keep the `SE` in the specified format:

```
df <- aggregate(
  . ~ ceiling(seq_along(SE)/2),
  FUN = paste, collapse = '+',
  data = df[with(df, order(factor(SE, levels = c(seq(SE[1], max(SE)), SE[!SE %in% seq(SE[1], max(SE))])))),]
  )[, -1]

df$eggs <- sapply(df$eggs, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

Output:

```
df

   SE eggs
1 4+5  3.0
2 6+7 14.0
3 8+1  3.5
4 2+3 15.0
```